# IE horizontal list : Last element is mysteriously offset

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem where IE 9 (and maybe other versions) does not display my horizontal list properly. As you can see, the rightmost element is pushed down a bit.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contentBlock">
    <ul id="Bubbles">
        <li id="First">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip...
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip...
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip... 
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip... 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul#Bubbles li {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-left:6px;
    padding:5px;
    background: #444; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#555), to(#333)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #555,  #333); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
    background: linear-gradient(#555, #333);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#555, #333);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#555555, #333333);
    float:left;
    width:225px;
    height:250px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding-top:3px;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    position:static;
    /*behavior:url(PIE.php);*/
}

#Bubbles {
    width:956px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline;
}

ul#Bubbles li#First {
    margin-left:0px;
    width:223px;
}

#contentBlock{
    height:270px;
}
```

I am using an IE9 version of CSS3PIE for background gradients, but it is disabled on these items for now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Tested in IE9 and it looks fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/yJX54/2/. This might suggest the issue lies elsewhere on your page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eCJGx/, I can't repro which probably means the problem is elsewhere on your page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by removing the div around the list. Thanks.